# Importing Acrobat file into Indesign and retaining comment highlights and text

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, import, highlights

I am aiming to import a multi page pdf into Adobe InDesign. The client has added highlighted comments which need to be retained when imported. However when the pages are brought in, the highlights disappear. The alternative is hours of work to recreate the highlights using yellow boxes set to multiply in the InDesign effects dialogue.

Is there a way to import or export the pdf with the highlighted comments left intact or is there some other straightforward method to save lots of man hours.

Comment: Since comments are "floating" essentially, and never *actually* part of the document, in Acrobat, I don't believe there is a way other than taking screenshots of the pages (which is a horrible solution).

Comment: Why the downvote??? I upvoted the question...

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 options

1) Open the PDF in Acrobat. Choose Preflight and search "flatten". Choose "Flatten annotations and form fields" and click "Analyze and fix". You will be asked to save a new PDF with the flattened comments.

2) If you only have Adobe Reader then you can export the pages as an image. To do this go to File -> Save As -> Image -> JPG.

Comment: You can also print to PDF, including any annotations.

Comment: @usr2564301 In my experience (mac) you still have to flatten the comments before printing to a PDF.

Comment: Thats amazing, you have saved my colleague about 4 hours worth of time reestablishing highlighted comments in several dozen pages. Thank you so much.